# Socket.io Page to Page

Tags: socket.io

This question follows lots of searching, on here and via Google. The examples for Socket.io vary an awful lot and (for a non-expert for me) are confusing.

I want to send data from one page to another via the server using Node.js and Socket.io. I don't want the server to serve the page, just get data from one page to another. As a first step I just want a basic page to connect and send some text.

For the server, I am using the following to receive:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

// Show a message in the console if anything connects to this server.
io.on('connection', function(socket){
     console.log('a user connected');
     });

// Listen on port 1337 and show this is happening by adding a message in
// the console.
http.listen(1337, function(){
           console.log('listening on *:1337');
           });

// If a message of type 'message' is receive display the content of
// the message.
io.on('message', function(message) {
     console.log(message);       
     });
```

For the first (source) page, I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Socket.io Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>Communication with socket.io</h1>
      <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
      <script>

        // Connect to the server on port 1337.
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');

        // Send a message of type 'message'.
        socket.emit('message', "Test");

      </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

I am probably just being naive and/or getting confused by all of the socket.io examples (or just being thick) but it doesn't seem to connect (i.e., no 'a user connected' message in the server console).

Any suggestions / advice would be gratefully received.

I honestly have searched this to death!

Thank you,

Hugh

Comment: One way you can do it is render your html page from server and in that page use `<script>var socket=io();</script>`.